# ReadDICOMSeries example with QVTKRenderWindowInteractor

Tags: python, pyqt5, vtk

I am trying to learn vtk and pyqt. For this reason I went through the following two examples and implemented the first one in python as well.

[ReadDICOMSeries](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadDICOMSeries)

[EmbedPyQt](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Widgets/EmbedPyQt)

However, when I tried to implement the DICOM series within a QMainWindow I ran into a problem. Though I don't get no error, nothing is rendered.

I tired different ways of implement the viewer, but here is simplified version my last attempt without interaction.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import vtk
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import sys


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # creat window
    main_window = QMainWindow()
    iwidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(main_window)
    main_window.setCentralWidget(iwidget)

    # set up dicom reader
    reader = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
    reader.SetDirectoryName('digest_article')
    reader.Update()

    # initialize renderer
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()

    # set up mapper
    slice_mapper = vtk.vtkImageSliceMapper()
    slice_mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

    # set random slice number
    slice_mapper.SetSliceNumber(5)

    # get render window from QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
    render_window = iwidget.GetRenderWindow()

    # add renderer to render window
    render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)

    # set up image_slice
    image_slice = vtk.vtkImageSlice()
    image_slice.SetMapper(slice_mapper)

    # set up window and level of image_slice
    MinMax = reader.GetOutput().GetScalarRange()

    image_slice_property = image_slice.GetProperty()
    image_slice_property.SetColorWindow(MinMax[1])
    image_slice_property.SetColorLevel((MinMax[1] - MinMax[0]) / 2)
    image_slice.Update()

    # set image_slice as input for renderer
    renderer.AddViewProp(image_slice)

    # show window
    main_window.show()

    render_window.Render()
    renderer.ResetCamera()
    render_window.Render()


    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above function leads to the fallowing output.

[Resulting Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF409.png)

Since there is no error I suspect that I initialize the rendering wrongly, or that I am missing something.

Do you think the problem is with the initialize?

How do need to initialize rendering in vtk, specifically with regard to the example above?

I would also be grateful for alternative theories.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should create the render window interactor.
try:

```
iren = render_window.GetInteractor()
```

then initialize the interactor at the end

```
iren.Initialize()
```